# DBUS warning message appears on login - org.freedesktop.DBUS.Error.Noreply

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, xfce, dbus

Following message appears on login : "Couldn't apply network settings. org.freedesktop.DBUS.Error.Noreply message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus). It may not be possible connect to bluetooth network using this computer"
It has been happening since installation of drivers from Xorg Edgers (they didn't work so I rollbacked them to Ubuntu default ones). Bluetooth actually works fine.
**My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS and my laptop is Acer Travelmate 250. DE is XFCE4**
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlAgw.jpg)

Comment: Provide information as text rather than image(s) (readable, searchable, etc).